# $X$ retracts onto its subspaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I see that if $X$ is a topological space and $x_0 \in X$ then $X$ retracts onto $\{ x_0 \}$ as if $f: \{ x_0 \} \to X: x_0 \mapsto x_0$ and $ g: X \to \{ x_0 \}: x \mapsto x_0 $ then $ g \circ f = id_{x_0}$.

My question is if in general, for any connected $A \subset X$ we have that $X$ retracts onto $A$.

Comment: One requires retracts to be continuous.

Comment: What do you mean? Both of my maps are continuous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the disk and it's boundary circle. The no retract theorem shows that no retraction can exist. To prove this you're going to need $\pi_1$ or $H_1$

Answer (score 1):

Disconnected subsets cannot be retracts of a connected space, because connectivity is preserved by continuous functions.

Comment: I forgot to include that $A$ should be a connected a subset. I see that for example if $X = [0,1]$ and $A=\{0,1\}$ then $X$ does not retract onto $A$

Answer (score 1):

Let $P$ be a property preserved under continuous maps. Let $X$ have property $P$ and let $A\subset X$ not have property $P$. Then $X$ cannot retract onto $A$ as the image of any continuous function from $X$ must also have property $P$ but the image of a retract onto $A$ is $A$ itself.

Examples:

- connectedness
- compactness
- trivial fundamental group (provided $X$ and $A$ are locally path-connected I believe)

etc

Answer (score 1):

Of course, trivially, any $\{p\} \subseteq X$ for $p \in X$ is a retract of $X$, for any $X$. But if $X$ is Hausdorff, a retract $A$ of $X$ must be closed in $X$. If $X$ is compact, $A$ also must be compact, and likewise for (path-)connectedness. 
If $X$ has the fixed point property, so must a retract (which is a reason why S^1$ is not a retract of the unit disk).

So e.g. $(0,1)$ is not a retract of $[0,1]$ e.g., as it's not closed/compact.